# Page Excerpt lengths different to post excerpt length on static home page

Tags: wordpress

I know there have been posts on this before, but I'm not sure I understand them or they seem like a lot of code for something that should be quite simple.

I have a static homepage that pulls in 3-page excerpts (that I need to be 41 words in length) and above I have the latest news post excerpt (which I need to be around 200 worlds length)

I have tried various things like :

```
function excerpt_length_category( $length ) {
    if (in_category( 'News' )) {
        return 200;
    } else {
        return 41;
    }
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length_category', 200  );
```

I also have a 'recent post widget extended' plugin, where I can set the latest news post excerpt in, but whatever I change it to, it doesn't change the excerpt length.

Any ideas welcome, brain struggling this morning and my js knowledge is practically non-existent.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, `in_category()` works just only inside WordPress loop, so, if You are on homepage, page has own ID.
Also, when You apply this filter, WordPress don't know, which page You try to load, cause there is chain of loading data and functions, and `in_category( 'News' )` return always `false`. Read Docs)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise only worked within loop